# How to make NHaml work with Asp.net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhaml

I'm trying to use NHaml as the ViewEngine in my asp.net MVC 6 Project.
I'm running this project on my OSX system via Mono. The NHaml documentation https://code.google.com/p/nhaml/wiki/Configuration says to use a .xml config file. But it looks like MVC 6 doesn't support xml config any more

```
'IConfigurationSourceRoot' does not contain a definition for 'AddXmlFile' 
and no extension method 'AddXmlFile' accepting a first argument 
of type 'IConfigurationSourceRoot' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I transfer this config to json syntax or just simply make this config right in code? This question maybe confusing, due to my very limited experience with .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i still didn't get it to run, but i think i moved a step forward because i know how to make `AddXmlFile()` work again, adding this line to project.json:

```
 "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Xml": "1.0.0-beta4",
```